# Setting up a game between two computers

Tags: engines

I was hoping that this would be a simple exercise but I have spent the last two days looking into this and can not find an answer (easy or otherwise). What I want to do is have my iMac play my Ubuntu laptop in chess over a LAN.

I know I can do this by manually entering the moves but my hope was to automate the process. And eventually play many games alternating parameter such and length of time per move etc.

Has any one done this or any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @Rafiek good question I suppose. Basically I have always a understood playing chess as a good benchmark of a computers processing abilities. So I wanted to have an novel way of pitting both machines against each other. Also it is Christmas and I am bored :)

Comment: I'm not sure if the computer as a whole can be benchmarked solely by use of chess engines. I'm absolutely sure that being bored is a valid reason for doing what you want to do! I would like to add that the process of setting up this "experiment" is a joyful and instructive experience.

Answer (score 5):

Get Arena!

Setup Arena on your iMac and Ubuntu computer. Register a computer account for each computer on a server of your choice. Of course, both computers need to login on the same server. Let one computer request a match and let the other computer accept the match.

That's it.

Arena is pretty cool. It wouldn't surprise me if you could create a script to automate a bunch of stuff you would want to do.

Comment: thanks for the response. quick question is the processing done on the server (arena) or on each local machine.

Comment: Processing is done on the local machines by the engines. The server is just a mediator for communication between the engines. Arena is not the server, but the Graphical User Interface for the chess engine. Arena can also act as a client for communication with a chess server.

Answer (score 0):

There are many free programs as well as commercial ones which can do this. Winboard (Xboard on Linux) is one free program where you can make two chess engines play each other. Shredder is comercial one where you can set to play chess engines against each other.

Comment: This would be a match on the same computer..?